# Unable to consume this JSON records in angular

Tags: php, angularjs, json, drupal

[image]
In the attached screenshot, I have configured the API in CORS ( drupal ), but still getting the error

> 10:41:21.021 Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy
>   disallows reading the remote resource at
>   http://happylife.in/techies/santaws_resources/santaws_resources.json.
>   (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match
>   'http://happylife.in/techies').1

Honestly this is duplicate thread, but I just changed few stuff, here is the API service hosted in public domain, lets try in your code and let me know, you can able to consume this JSON records in your ANGULAR code  OR NOT But I can able to read this JSON in PHP program.

> http://happylife.in/techies/santaws_resources/santaws_resources.json

[api](http://happylife.in/techies/santaws_resources/santaws_resources.json)

Answer (score 1):

Due to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy, an application running in a browser by default cannot fetch (via XHR) a resource from another origin (domain, in your case). PHP doesn't have this limitation. To fetch a resource from another origin, there are various browser-side techniques as well as the option to proxy the fetch through your backend.

Comment: any suggestion, for this solution. i should write any code against this cross origin issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) issue.

You need to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with your response for it to work.

---

**Update for edit1**

The error

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match

means that this header doesn't contain the name of your site. Please check if you receive this header in the following format.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'http://www.yoursite.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

In drupal
step 1 and 2 solved the issue.

step 1
[image]

step 2
[image]